# CakePHP Routing query

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, croogo

How do I show the URL through `CroogoRouter::connect` function in CakePHP? 
I passed the name of controller and action my routes file like:

```
CroogoRouter::connect('/', array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index'));
```

and I get redirected to the dashboard page, but I do not see the URL properly. I want my URL as `localhost/abc/admin/dashboard` and it is showing as `localhost/abc` only.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the webroot (`/`) as route alias, it will not show the `admin/dashboard` bit. If you **really** want that (I'd discourage it if it's just for fancy display purposes), you should create a simple controller action that redirects. For example if you alter the route to this:

```
CroogoRouter::connect('/', array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'home'));
```

And then in the `DashboardsController` create this action:

```
public function home() {
    $this->autoRender = false; // We have no view, so don't render anything
    $this->redirect(array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index'));
}
```

It should display the URL as you want it. Again, if it's only for display purposes (to make it look "nice") and not for any SEO kind of purpose, I'd discourage using such an ugly workaround. But it should do the trick either way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the controller name i think controller name should be dashboards or something.

check this link may be helpful http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Frank/2009/11/02/cakephp-s-routing-explained